# Logic for Using Layout XML Files

Tags: java, android

I have started learning Android App Development. I want to ask that if in my Android app my ListView has 50 list items(city names).
When a user clicks on a list item I want to show data of each list city in a new activity.Do I need to make 50 layouts for each city data? What should I use?

Comment: No. Each item wil use the same layout you provide **once**. Which layout to use depends on your single item design.

Comment: Welcome young developer Rohn!

Comment: You mean it has 50 views or 50 attributes? If it's 50 views, yes you'll have to list all 50 in the XML. Much cleaner and easier to manipulate than making them all programatically in the java file. If you want just one screen - Just one activity will do!

Comment: No, you don't have to do that. the idea of a listview is to have different rows which have the same layout but with different content, so you will create only one layout for all rows

Comment: Not sure what you mean when you say override the XML. What are you trying to accomplish and what is the difficulty?

Comment: Search for custom list view. You will get your answer.

Comment: See this [tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_list_view.htm)

Comment: You dont need to have 50 layouts , it can be possible in two layouts only one for show list and other to show details. so if you want to show city detail you need to pass some city name or city id for this you can use webservices or sqlite. on the basis of city name or city id, you can fetch all details of perticular city

Comment: I want to create an activity that shows information of each city. So for 50 cities do I need to make 50 activities?

Comment: yes Anshul I want that!

Comment: OK than let us know that are you aware of web services or sqlite in android?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use recyclerview instead of listview for listing all 50 items. No need to design for 50 times. You need to have adapter class for the repetition of Listitems to be listed.

you have to design an XMl page for ListView, another XML for ListViewItem. Just link together in Java and adapter class, which gives the output of lists with autoscrolling.

refer this tutorial[: tutorial page](http://www.androidhive.info/2016/01/android-working-with-recycler-view/)

Download the code and run in IDE.. You will get what u want

Comment: I want to have a list acitvity and an detail activty. So how should i go with detail activity?

Comment: You can animate ur app using Uplabs website. They provide sourcecode for some of the animations. U can find lot here. 
https://material.uplabs.com/posts/expandablerecyclerview

Comment: Well thanks, at least I now know about the adapter and recycler view! Would be great if you could guide me more on app development lucnodroid@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

No, we don't want to create 50 different layouts for each item, so we use a listview. We create only one XML-file for our item and using adapter we create 50 objects for our items.
I think you should use recyclerview instead of listview.
[tutorial for recylcerview](http://www.androidhive.info/2016/01/android-working-with-recycler-view/)